# CSS3 animation (with rotation and movement and scaling) not working

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of code where I want to move the image of a Voyager 1 shuttle from left to right, all the while having it spin and become from small to a larger size and then coming to a stop at the final destination. I am using the below code but it doesn't work . I mean nothing happens at all. Could anyone please look at it and let me know if I am doing it right ? I am a beginner to CSS & CSS3. Thanks!

**HTML**:

```
<div class = "voyager">
  <img class="shuttle" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/2s66hyc.jpg" />
  </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
@keyframes left-right {
    0%{left:44%;}
    100%{left:100%;}        
}    
@-webkit-@keyframes left-right {
    0%{left:44%;}
    100%{left:100%};
}    
@keyframes big-small {
    0% {transform:scale(0.25);}
    25% {transform:scale(0.5);}
    50% {transform:scale (0.50);}
    75% {transform:scale (0.75);}
    100% {transform:scale(1);}        
}
@-webkit-@keyframes big-small {
    0% {transform:scale(0.25);}
    25% {transform:scale(0.5);}
    50% {transform:scale (0.50);}
    75% {transform:scale (0.75);}
    100% {transform:scale(1);}        
}
@keyframes spinning {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}    
@-webkit-@keyframes spinning {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.shuttle {     
  top:50px;
  position:relative;
  left:44%;  
  animation: spinning 4s 1s 3 linear normal,
             big-small 4s 1s 3 linear normal,
             left-right 4s 1s 3 linear normal;

  -webkit-animation: spinning 4s 1s 3 linear normal,
                     big-small 4s 1s 3 linear normal,
                     left-right 4s 1s 3 linear normal;      
}
```

Comment: Fiddle here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrbezcmt/)

Comment: thanks! forgot to include it.

Comment: The shuttle moves in FF but doesn't spin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `@-webkit-@keyframes`

It should be `@-webkit-keyframes` and so on.

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rrbezcmt/1/)

Comment: also, I was wondering, is there a property where I could specify a style where the animation stays where it is at the end, and not come back to its starting position ?

Comment: As I recall it's [**Animation-fill-mode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) and "forwards"

Comment: Just one more thing, the big-small function only seems to work at the end, for example the shuttle scales from small to big only in the last frame, is it possible for it to simultaneously get small to big right along as the animation proceeds (spinning as it goes from left to right) ? the way I have specified it shouldn't that work ?

Comment: I'm sure it is but you'd have to experiment with different values to try it out.

Comment: I just tried, but it doesn't seem to work. I am now trying that the big-small happens for the first 3s then at the 4s point the rotation and the spinning starts. I used [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h_i_r_a/4Logjuaw/7/) code but in FF it zooms at first then moves from left to right (the way I want) but doesn't rotate simultaneously. In chrome it rotates and moves from left to right but doesn't zoom from small to big. In codepen, the same code rotates and moves from left to right, and then the big-small happens  as before. I've added the moz prefixes too. What do you think could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

keyframes CSS property DOES NOT require '@' symbol with browser prefix. Updated CSS:

```
@keyframes left-right {
    0%{left:44%;}
    100%{left:100%;}        
}    
@-webkit-keyframes left-right {
    0%{left:44%;}
    100%{left:100%};
}    
@keyframes big-small {
    0% {transform:scale(0.25);}
    25% {transform:scale(0.5);}
    50% {transform:scale (0.50);}
    75% {transform:scale (0.75);}
    100% {transform:scale(1);}        
}
@-webkit-keyframes big-small {
    0% {transform:scale(0.25);}
    25% {transform:scale(0.5);}
    50% {transform:scale (0.50);}
    75% {transform:scale (0.75);}
    100% {transform:scale(1);}        
}
@keyframes spinning {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}    
@-webkit-keyframes spinning {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.shuttle {     
  top:50px;
  position:relative;
  left:44%;  
  animation: spinning 4s 1s 3 linear normal,
             big-small 4s 1s 3 linear normal,
             left-right 4s 1s 3 linear normal;

  -webkit-animation: spinning 4s 1s 3 linear normal,
                     big-small 4s 1s 3 linear normal,
                     left-right 4s 1s 3 linear normal;      
}
```